# Playing DRM protected content on Android using Azure Media Services

Tags: android, azure-media-services, widevine

I am trying to play DRM protected content (using Widevine) on Android. I am using Azure Media Services to host the content and distribute licenses. The content plays seamlessly on most of the devices while it gives an error

> Failed to create MediaCodec: video/x-vnd.on2.vp8, isSecure: true
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to initialize OMX.qcom.video.decoder.vp8.secure

on some devices such as Nexus 5. I have tried to search a lot but couldn't find a relevant solution to this.

Comment: Can you please share more details on how you are hosting content on Azure Media Services - are you using our service to encode to H.264/AAC, and applying Widevine common encryption as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-protect-with-playready-widevine?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Anil. I am encoding mp4 using adaptive mutibitrate encoding, and publishing it as mpeg-dash to get an .ism file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Anil. I am encoding mp4 using adaptive mutibitrate encoding, and publishing it as mpeg-dash to get an .ism file.

Comment: Thanks - so the DASH stream will contain H.264 video and AAC audio. However, the error message refers to the vp8 video codec. Is the device capable of playing H.264/AAC?

Comment: Looking at this thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710310/what-android-devices-decoder-has-supported-adaptive-video-playback) - it appears that the Nexus 5 series did not support AVC (H.264) decoding in hardware. 
It also appears that device never supported any form of adaptive streaming playback either, so it would not natively playback MPEG-DASH either.

Comment: Looks like there are some good details here from Android on how to query the device capabilities - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.html#FEATURE_AdaptivePlayback

Comment: I tried playing AES protected video on Nexus. It seems to play perfectly, so I guess Nexus is able to play Adaptive streaming with MPEG-Dash.